# Accessing jQuery itself, and other globals from within jQote2 template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, jqote

Using `jQote`, my templates compile properly into lamdas unless I use things like `$.each()`, or attempt to access other globals like my own environment variables accessed through `_.*` ... similar to how `jQuery` is accessed through `$.*`

My tags are setup to be `<* *>` ... I need to be able to do things like this:

```
<* $.each( this.scheduled, function( i, s ) { *>
    <a href="<*= _.base *>/.calendar/goto/<*= s.timestamp *>">
        <*= s.readable *>
    </a>
<* }) *>
```

Doing that for example gets me this error, for using `$._` ... and if I change from `$.each()` to `for() { }` for example, then `_.*` triggers the same kind of error:

```
Expected an identifier but found 'out' instead
```

Looking at successfully compiled templates, `out` is the `string` that `jQote2` is filling with a parsed template, populated with data. All I can really access is the `this` which contains my data.

How do I access global variables inside `jQote2` templates without triggering this obscure error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It was not a scope issue at all!

After extensive digging, and validation of the code generated by `jQote2`, this is all it ended up being:

```
<* $.each( this.scheduled, function( i, s ) { *>
    <a href="<*= _.base *>/.calendar/goto/<*= s.timestamp *>">
        <*= s.readable *>
    </a>
<* }); *>
```

Let's zoom in on the one character that made all the difference: `<* }); *>`

**Missing SEMI-COLON!** Being sure to completely close code blocks seems extremely important with the level of compression applied to templates, once they are compiled.